# receiving an error when trying to change a column type from string to a float in python

Tags: python, pandas, jupyter-notebook

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv("dataset.csv")
trying to change an object type to float

df['Charge'] = (df['Charge']).astype('float')
```

```
ValueError: could not convert string to float: '(94.00)'
```

There are no commas or special characters in data just . and i need to keep decimal point

however it will allow me to change to string but I need it as a float because i get errors when try to work on a string

Comment: Need a problematic sample of dataset.csv

Comment: Isn't error message explicit enough?

Comment: I could take some guesses.  But it would be easier if OP offered up a sample.

Comment: there are mostly decimal point numbers in the dataset column 74.00 68.99 94.00 58.32 68.59

Comment: Try: `pd.to_numeric(df['Charge'].str.strip('()'), errors='coerce')`

Answer (score 0):

> ValueError: could not convert string to float: '(94.00)'

So you have this `str`ing: `'(94.00)'`. Do you know what `(94.00)` is? A `tuple` containing a single `float`, and not a `float`.

So, if you want to get the `94.00` from inside the tuple, you have to cast to float only the part of the string without `()`.

Comment: It's definitely not a tuple. It's a string.

Comment: it was an object and i can convert to string but not to a float

Answer (score 0):

you cant convert a (94.00) to float but you can do it to 94.00
So you can use a delimiter

[this](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html) may help you

Comment: I need change the entire column to a float but keeps giving an error, do you know what I could do to resolve this

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes I have the same issue too. The problem here is the parenthesis: `()`

So I first remove them with regex:

```
df['Charge'].str.replace('\(','',regex=True).str.replace('\)','',regex=True)
```

Then I apply`.astype(float)`

Here my TestDf:

```
df_test=pd.DataFrame(['(201536.34)','(133104.47)', '66579.82', '95129.99', 
'72333.23', '61319.77', '60705.00', '47944.47', '35510.36', ('28530.77')])

df_test[0]
Out[47]: 
0    (201536.34)
1    (133104.47)
2       66579.82
3       95129.99
4       72333.23
5       61319.77
6       60705.00
7       47944.47
8       35510.36
9       28530.77
Name: 0, dtype: object
```

When trying to convert it to float I get the same error as you: `ValueError: could not convert string to float: '(201536.34)'`

```
df_test[0]=df_test[0].str.replace('\(','',regex=True).str.replace('\)','',regex=True)

df_test[0]
Out[72]: 
0    201536.34
1    133104.47
2     66579.82
3     95129.99
4     72333.23
5     61319.77
6     60705.00
7     47944.47
8     35510.36
9     28530.77
Name: 0, dtype: object
```

Now ready to use `astype('float)`

```
df_test[0].astype('float')
Out[74]: 
0    201536.34
1    133104.47
2     66579.82
3     95129.99
4     72333.23
5     61319.77
6     60705.00
7     47944.47
8     35510.36
9     28530.77
Name: 0, dtype: float64
```